# Create / Config Azure Devops CI/CD deployment for Azure Webapp using ARM template or C# Sdk

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

Below commands when run from **cloud Shell**, sets up **CI/CD** properly from **Azure DevOps** project.

```
az login

az webapp deployment source config --name "{azurewebappname}" --resource-group "{webappunderresourcegroupname}" --repository-type vsts --repo-url "https://{accountname}.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_git/{reponame}" --branch master --cd-app-type AspNetCore --cd-project-url "https://{accountname}.visualstudio.com/{projectname}"  --subscription "{subscriptionid}"  --private-repo-password "{vsts-alias-username}" --private-repo-username "{vsts-alias-password}"
```

I am looking for equivalent solution via **ARM Template** or **C# SDK** or **REST API**.

[Azure-Cli documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deployment-source-config)

**NOTE: I am using ARM Template via C#**

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, because you can configure a source, but I dont know how to configure credentials, its not exposed in the same api. [here's](https://github.com/4c74356b41/bbbb-is-the-word/blob/master/_arm/webapp-git.json#L143) how to create source control with the arm template.

Comment: Maybe you can try the REST API [Web Apps - Create Or Update Source Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdatesourcecontrol).

Comment: Charles Xu have tried that already

Comment: Charles - Update source control doesn't setup continuous deployment with azure vsts/devops.

Comment: @CharlesXu - I found solution, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From C#, there is a working code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-dotnet-deploy-using-arm-template) to deploy an ARM template. The example will log into Azure, create a resource group, deploy an ARM template and then delete the template.

Note this sample gets the Azure credentials from a file using [AzureCredentialsFactory](http://AzureCredentialsFactory). To complete the authorization part, I've found it easiest to create a service principal, save the credentials to a secure file and use it in the app. For a working code sample, look `[here][3]`.

For examples of pre-built ARM Templates, see this web page that has pointers to over 15 solutions that can be deployed directly into Azure is at:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/samples-resource-manager-templates.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/samples-resource-manager-templates)

I believe the one you are interested in is: [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-github-deploy), which deploys a webapp that is connected to a github repository.

Answer (score 0):

Well after debugging [Azure CLI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) on local system, looking in to the request/response azure-cli sends/receives for command asked in question, found below request flow - might help somebody.

```
# 1. Get tenant's access token - not covered here, check microsoft's ADAL documentation.
# 2. Get vsts access token
curl -X POST \
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token \  
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \  
-d 'grant_type=refresh_token&resource=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798&refresh_token={insert_tenant_refresh_token_here}&client_id=04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46'


# 3. Provision CI/CD configuration
curl -X POST 'https://{insert_azuredevops_account_name}.portalext.visualstudio.com/_apis/continuousdelivery/provisioningconfigurations?api-version=3.2-preview.1' \
 -H 'authorization: Bearer {insert_tenant_access_token_here}' \
 -H 'content-type: application/json' \
 -d '{"source": {"type": "codeRepository", "buildConfiguration": {"type": "AspNetCore"}, "repository": {"defaultBranch": "master", "type": "TfsGit", "id": "{insert_repository_id}"}}, "targets": [{"environmentType": "production", "authorizationInfo": {"scheme": "Headers", "parameters": {"Authorization": "Bearer {insert_vsts_access_token}"}}, "resourceGroupName": "{insert_webapp_resource_group_name}", "tenantId": "{insert_tenant_id}", "location": "Central India", "subscriptionName": "{insert_azure_webapp_subscription_name}", "provider": "azure", "friendlyName": "Production", "subscriptionId": "{insert_azure_webapp_subscription_id}", "resourceIdentifier": "{insert_azure_webapp_name}", "type": "windowsAppService"}], "ciConfiguration": {"project": {"name": "{insert_vsts_project_name}"}}}'
```

Good Luck!